# IOException thrown by NetworkStream.Read() connected to netcat instance after short amount of inactivity?

Tags: c#, .net, powershell

I have a `NetworkStream` object that is connected to a remote `netcat` instance. Everything works, while I type at the keyboard and data gets transmitted between the hosts.

```
$serverStream.Read($bytes, 0, $bytes.Length))
```

However, after ~60 seconds of inactivity, I receive the below error (`IOException`) in `Read()`. Reading the documentation tells me that `IOException` is thrown, when the socket is closed.

I've used `netcat` alot and has never experienced that it disconnects sessions. So, the problem is related to `NetworkStream`, I guess?

How can I prevent `$serverStream.Read()` from throwing an exception, and instead just wait until data is available (keeping the session intact)?

**NetworkStream**:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.sockets.networkstream.read?view=netframework-4.8

```
Exception calling "Read" with "3" argument(s): "Unable to read data from the transport connection: A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or establishe
d connection failed because connected host has failed to respond."
At C:\Users\bd6164\Desktop\phishing_revsh.ps1:31 char:9
+ while (($i = $serverStream.Read($bytes, 0, $bytes.Length)) -ne 0) {
+         ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [], MethodInvocationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : IOException
```

Answer (score 1):

**Netcat**

Are you sure you haven't set a timeout?

**NetworkStream**

You can set the reading timeout for a network stream with this line:

> networkStream.ReadTimeout = *milliseconds*;

---

Maybe this will help you:

https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/424125/ncat-command-gives-idle-timeout-expired-on-using-option-i

Comment: Thank you, I just checked my `netcat`. It supports a `-w timeout` option, but the default is infinite. However, `networkStream.ReadTimeout` results in 100000. I can ensure you that I haven't set any timeout in my 40 lines of PowerShell code??? The default value is infinite (see documentation). Can it be that my `NetworkStream` is derived from a `System.Net.HttpWebRequest`?

Comment: One possibility would be to send keep alive messages to get sure it does not disconnect. To find the problem please try connecting to another server and see if it's still there. PS: networkstream uses sockets